# ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved - Forcing nested redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

Morning All,

After spending most of the night figuring out how to put a limit on my model creation I finally got somewhere. The nested statement is now presenting me with not saved which is great news.

However I cannot seem to get the redirect or flash[:base] to work. Here is the code below:

```
class SnippetsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :find_book

   def create
   if @snippet = @book.snippets.create!(params[:snippet])
      redirect_to @book
    else
      flash[:base]
      #render 
   end
 end     


def approve
   #@snippet = @book.snippet.find(params[:id])
    if @snippet.update_attribute(:approved, true)
    redirect_to users_path
  else
   render root_path
  end 
end

  def edit
    @snippet = @book.snippets.find(params[:id])
  end    

  def update
    @snippet = @book.snippets.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @snippet.update_attributes(params[:snippet])
        format.html { redirect_to @book, notice: 'Comment was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def find_book

    @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  end
end
```

Models parent (book)

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :snippets
  attr_accessible :title, :book_id, :size

  def snippets_limit_reached?
   if size == 0
    self.snippets.count >= 2
    elsif size == 1
       self.snippets.count >= 3
     elsif size == 2
       self.snippets.count >= 4
     else
       return false
  end
 end
end
```

Child (Snippet)

```
class Snippet < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :check_limit
  belongs_to :book
   attr_accessible :content, :book_id 

  validates :book_id, presence: true


    def check_limit         
      if book.snippets_limit_reached?
        errors.add :base, 'Snippet limit reached.'           
        return false
      end       
      return true
    end 
end
```

Let me know if you need anything else, just fyi when it's running I cannot get past the nested create!

```
if @snippet = @book.snippets.create!(params[:snippet])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bang methods (create!, save!) throw errors when unsuccessful, instead of returning, what evaluates to false.

Removing the bang should fix this problem.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know a bang did that so will avoid it where I can